# jQuery using 'this' - thumbnails swap images, Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering if jQuery's **'this'** could streamline my code?

Full code here
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/7ORr

Thanks for help, any suggestions appreciated.

jQuery Code

```
/*
Ref: http://api.jquery.com/hover/
Calling $( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut ) is shorthand for:
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
*/

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.fd-fade1').hover(function() {
        // img1
        $('img.fd-img1').fadeIn('slow');
    },
    function() {
        $("img.fd-img1").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    // img2
    $('.fd-fade2').hover(function() {
        $('img.fd-img2').fadeIn('slow');
    },
    function() {
        $("img.fd-img2").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    // img3
    $('.fd-fade3').hover(function() {
        $('img.fd-img3').fadeIn('slow');
    },
    function() {
        $("img.fd-img3").fadeOut("slow");
    });

}); // end document.ready function
```

Comment: jQuery's `this`? What do you mean by that? Every JS has a `this` "variable", it has nothing to do with jQuery. The best improvement would probably be to store the selector of the related element in a `data-*` attribute, and then use something like `$($(this).data('related'))` to get a reference to it.

Comment: Yes it could...please post the HTML markup and not a link to bootsnipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could certainly condense your code using `this`. For example, if you added the `.fading` class to all of the parent `<div>` elements of the images you wanted to fade in/out, so your HTML for each one looked something like this:

```
<div class="fd-fade1 fading">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yxAxCaK.jpg" class="fd-img1" alt="">
</div>
```

Then you would only need one set of `hover()` callbacks in your JavaScript to do the colour fade effect, by leveraging the callbacks' context with `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fading').hover(function () {
        $(this).children("img").fadeIn('slow');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("img").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/An2EK/2/) to demonstrate the code in action.

Oh right, and if you wanted to stop the chaining of fades (not sure if you noticed that happening), you can just use jQuery's `stop()` when right before fading, like so:

```
$(this).children("img").stop().fadeIn('slow');
$(this).children("img").stop().fadeOut("slow");
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I looked at [link](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) and tried those two lines. But I don't see why I would .stop animation, I changed 'slow' to 4000 to see effect of chaining. But I didn't notice a difference, I want the image to fade out, while the other image is fading in.  What am I not understanding.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, well, if you quickly move your mouse over and off of the image repeatedly, you'll probably find that the animations build up in a queue - to stop this from happening, the `stop()` clears the queue, so the animation won't keep playing back and forth after you stop hovering over the image.

Comment: Here's an example using `stop()` in the full code, you can compare it to the JSFiddle without the `stop()`. http://jsfiddle.net/jHUV7/1/

Comment: >"if you quickly move your mouse over and off of the image repeatedly, you'll probably find that the animations build up in a queue"  - **Now I get it :**, and I want to use '.stop()', that is behavior desired. Thanks. R